# Move audio stream from OpenAL application to different audio device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, external-soundcard

I have two different audio output devices: an internal sound card and an external DAC/amp.

When starting an OpenAL application (I first observed the issue with Minecraft, but I suspect it affects all applications that use OpenAL for audio playback), the internal sound card is selected for output, and I cannot change the device using `pavucontrol` (or KMixer on Kubuntu). The option to select an alternate device is present, but choosing the device has no effect.

How can I select an alternate audio playback device for OpenAL applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add the option `allow-moves = true` to the OpenAL configuration file (the per-user file is located at `~/.alsoftrc`).

If you don't already have this file (it doesn't exist by default), you can copy it from `/etc/openal/alsoft.conf` or use this [sample default configuration](http://repo.or.cz/w/openal-soft.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/alsoftrc.sample).